# is xampp a security threat if it is run on a my mom's laptop?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, virtual-hosts

Can xampp configured with virtual hosts cause a security threat if it is run on a computer used as a normal computer and not a server? Example: I want to run xampp with virtual hosts on my mom's mac laptop. She uses it for emails, web-surfing, etc. Would this put her at risk for being hacked or personal information at risk? Thank you in advance!

Comment: no it wont put her at any risk.

Comment: @Xatenev You cannot say that. You don't know what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @arkascha ur right, but that wasnt what he asked. He asked if xampp is a secury threat - and xampp is NO security threat - it does NOT make your pc more vulnerable on its own.

Comment: @Xatenev Though that is right it is a cynical answer. Obviously the OP wants to install that software to use it.

Comment: Yeah, but how is he using it? Do they plan on hosting a live site, or using it internally to verify fixes, or for testing?

Comment: Ok, since all the "experts" here tell you that there is no issue with running that stuff on someone else computer I'd say decide yourself. Although I'd suggest to leave the decision to your mom, _after_ she saw the discussion here... After all it is _her_ system, _her_ data and _her_ live.

Comment: @arkascha "experts"? Honestly, running xampp on a local system does NOT create any security issues - or can you tell me of any? xampp does NOT communicate with anything outside of your local system - so the hackers can only access your server by having access to your network if you did NOT make any relevant changes to anything else. and when a hacker has access to your network, its too late anyways.

Comment: @Xatenev I never claimed that xampp itself is a security issue. I claim that is opens potential issues depending on what you do with it. Since the OP did not specify for what purpose he wants to install it I am not able to tell him that xampp is generally without security implications. That's all: it depends. If in doubt, then be conservative. _Especially_ when talking about someone elses system. I sketched an example scenario below in the comments to an answer which definitely _does_ exist, and if that http server is used then more issues may arise.

Comment: @Xatenev About that netowrk issue: why is it a problem if "someone has access to your network"? Why don't you apply the same logic you used before here? Why is this suddenly the other way 'round for you? A well configured system does not suffer from being accessible by network, that is what systems are built for in the end these days. And note, that the OP did _not_ write anything about some private / separated network. You don't know anything about the situation, nevertheless you make statements. That does not make sense, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can deny all ip address and just add exception to no one can access the webserver
i think phpmyadmin used in xampp and appserv have vulnerability and can get shell access to

.htaccess file for deny ip :

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 111.222.333.444
```

111.222.333.444 => ip allowed

if you deny port 80 for other ip , it should be safe :D
by the way should take care about services you run on your operation system

Comment: You will always have to allow access by the system itself, most web applications and the like require that. Thus there _always_ is a security risk. Just imagine a html email "the mom" reads (everyone today thinks html emails are a good idea, whyever), it might contain links to the loopback address. Who knows what risks that might trigger?

Comment: i don't think so javascript enable on html mails !

Comment: so what's wrong if not enable :P ? :D i think it's safe

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no such thing as "a server", not in the way you obviously understand the term. "A server" is nothing but a simple computer that "serves" something, thus the term. Every computer is a server and every computer is a client. Whyever, somehow the term "a server" has become common for systems used mainly to server things, like for example "web server". That does not change the fact that the expression does not really make sense from a technical point of view.
2. certainly running a *server software* on any system adds a security risk to that system, since it exposes the system, makes it communicative. That is the sense of using a server software, so there is way around that. You can only try to limit the security thread, you cannot prevent it.
3. In the end it absolutely depends on what you server with `xampp` used as a "server software". There are many many web applications out there that pose *high* security risks on the system they run on. Bad programmed applications, unknown issues, all the bandwidth.
4. In addition the configuration of the server software is crucial when it comes to security. You can easily leave wide open gaps and accidentially make private data accessible to the public or risk that the system is taken over and turned into a bot or a zombie. So you should limit access to the system as far as possible. Block everything you do not really need. And, preferably, do not connect such a system to the internet, if you only need it internally.

So the answer clearly is YES, THERE IS A SECURITY RISK. 
You should only run server software if you know what you do and if you know how to handle it. 
And you certainly should *never* do that on someone elses system!

Comment: Using your logic, everything is a security threat. Running a program. Visiting a website. Joining the internet in a public place. All computers have the ability to communicate, adding server software doesn't change that.

Comment: @Blaine There is some truth in that. Indeed everything you do may hold a security thread. Why is that wrong? The OPs question was if there _is_ a security thread. There was _no_ mentioning of any details. So what else should one answer?

Comment: The answer is: it depends. Without more information we don't know. There are instances where is is fine and will not cause ANY threat. There are times that it will. So, like with most questions, the answer depends on the context of the question.

Comment: @Blaine I absolutely agree! That is why I am so frustrated about everyone here stating that there is no security issue. If in doubt, then be careful and warn.

Comment: Right, but don't tell them there is always a threat, because that is just as presumptive as saying there isn't one.

Comment: @Blaine So you say: if in doubt then just tell people it's fine, when they are insecure and already ask for help? Ok...

Answer (score -2):

The answer here is: it depends.

If you are using this for internal support, then no. This will not cause a serious security risk on her computer. At least no more than anything else you do. Yes, by adding the server software, you can have other computers connect to it, but it depends on what you are doing with this server. If you are using it for internal development, you'll be fine. If you are THAT worried about it, make sure you aren't connected to the internet. However, if you are trying to host a web site with high traffic, then you may want to consider another option, like an actual server, rather than a local host.

To be honest, there is a security risk in EVERYTHING you do. Connecting to the internet in a coffee shop. Visiting web sites. Opening emails. They are ALL risks. So you just have to understand what you are doing. By adding virtual hosts, you can connect one computer to another; however, if this is for testing, and doing things internally, the chances of someone getting that IP address is extremely low.

Comment: Very strange view. For example: "By adding virtual hosts, you can connect one computer to another"... that is utter nonsense!

Comment: Computers are connected using cables, network technology like protocols and requests. Virtual hosts are a protocol internal detail, that is name resolution and reaction to it. It has nothing to do with connecting.

Comment: That reaction is done via a network, using those same protocols. Whether it's a LAN, VPN, WAN, or what have you. It uses the same technology and protocols.

Comment: No, such a reaction is not "done via a network". It is a server internal aspect.

Comment: Depends on the reaction? There is a network element to the process. That internal process doesn't do anything without the request, which generally comes from a network.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So why do you write that "virtual hosts connect computers"?